# Angular UI Bootstrap (Jade, Angular, Express) progressbar not working

Tags: pug, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm having trouble displaying the progress bar in UI Bootstrap. I have listed the dependency in my other js file (angular.modeul('ui.bootstrap.demo',.....) and I have done npm install angular, and npm install angular-ui-bootstrap. I have also imported everything I need (straight from plunker). I'm really having trouble figuring this out. I think there may be something wrong with my jade code:

```
doctype html
html(ng-app='ui.bootstrap.demo')
  head
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.js')
    script(src='http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.js')
    script(src='example.js')
    link(href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
  body
    div(ng-controller='ProgressDemoCtrl')
      small
        em Object (changes type based on value)
      uib-progressbar.progress-striped.active(value='dynamic', type='{{type}}')
        | {{type}} 
        i(ng-show='showWarning') !!! Watch out !!!
```

The result on the screen is: {{type}} !!! Watch out !!!

Edit: Just checked the html output of the jade code and it matches the html code for the UI Progressbar. I am lost...it works fine in plunker but not when I run it with my node app?

EDIT: Posted example.js

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ProgressDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.max = 200;

  $scope.random = function() {
    var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    var type;

    if (value < 25) {
      type = 'success';
    } else if (value < 50) {
      type = 'info';
    } else if (value < 75) {
      type = 'warning';
    } else {
      type = 'danger';
    }

    $scope.showWarning = type === 'danger' || type === 'warning';

    $scope.dynamic = value;
    $scope.type = type;
  };

  $scope.random();

  $scope.randomStacked = function() {
    $scope.stacked = [];
    var types = ['success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger'];

    for (var i = 0, n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1); i < n; i++) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        $scope.stacked.push({
          value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 1),
          type: types[index]
        });
    }
  };

  $scope.randomStacked();
});
```

Console Error: Console Error: SyntaxError: expectred expression, got '<' in example.js:1:0? Something is wrong with my example.js but my jade file does reside in the same path as example.js

Comment: Can you publish the content of example.js ?

Comment: Just published example.js

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Yes I see errors. 'Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap.demo due to Module 'ui.bootstrap.demo' is not available. You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have URIs starting with // in jour script tags

just add `http` or `https`

```
doctype html
html(ng-app='ui.bootstrap.demo')
  head
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.js')
    script(src='http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.js')
    script(src='example.js')
    link(href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
  body
    div(ng-controller='ProgressDemoCtrl')
      small
        em Object (changes type based on value)
      uib-progressbar.progress-striped.active(value='dynamic', type='{{type}}')
        | {{type}} 
        i(ng-show='showWarning') !!! Watch out !!!
```

compiled:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="ProgressDemoCtrl"><small><em>Object (changes type based on value)</em></small>
    <uib-progressbar value="dynamic" type="{{type}}" class="progress-striped active">{{type}} <i ng-show="showWarning">!!! Watch out !!!</i></uib-progressbar>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You should see something like

[image: bar]

otherwise add your error messages to your question.

It worked in plunker 'cause it adds this automaticaly or has the js-libs in its relative path.

Comment: just tried. Actually it doesn't work but now I see errors on the console! That means it definitely helped

Comment: Console Error: SyntaxError: expectred expression, got '<'  in example.js:1:0? Something is wrong with my example.js but my jade file does reside in the same path as example.js

Comment: You'll propably have '<' as the first char in your file. Does it start with a script tag? Remove it or just copy your example.js as you published it above.

Comment: It actually doesn't start with that. I'm so confused. I did copy the example.js I had above but still giving me that error

Comment: Just tried using it without Nodejs and it works. So it probably has to do something with my routing. Thanks by the way!